# How much padding does the Banno plugin framework use in mobile views?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

When using the Banno plugin framework, how much of the screen width does the Banno plugin framework use up?

For example, given an iphone with a viewport size of 375px. If the Banno framework has padding of 24px on each side, that would leave 327px left for the plugin to use.

How much padding does the plugin framework us on each side in a mobile view? How much width will the plugin actually get?

Answer (score 0):

That's not explicitly specified as the answer can vary between operating systems (and versions) as well as based on the specific device.

You'll get the full width of the *Card Face* as defined in the [User Interface](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/) doc. Plugin content should be responsive to adapt to varying widths. (The height is [configured](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/configuration/) and known in advance.)

These resources may be helpful as well, when designing your plugin:

- https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/
- https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/launching-your-project/design-your-plugin/