# Banno plugin framework sizing

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

@jaime, hi, I'm part of Brian's team, appreciate the help ([How much padding does the Banno plugin framework use in mobile views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971956/how-much-padding-does-the-banno-plugin-framework-use-in-mobile-views/73000388#73000388)). There are some inconsistencies with the docs and our tests. We did the test on an Iphone 12 Pro Max, which is a pretty big phone.

Our widgets have the following specs - Minimum height: 400px Maximum height: 400px Supported widths: 264px to 336px Recommended width for best result: 300px

We're seeing the following in our tests, which also forces padding around the card faces

[Our plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fx4X.png)

The JH/Banno docs are showing a full-width widget, which isn't replicated

[Banno's docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLLtS.png)

Appreciate any help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin content does get the full width of the *Card Face*, although you would have to be careful with any margins set on your content.

You can set a background color (e.g. something like neon green or hot pink) to verify.

Notably, that is in relation to the *Card Face* width, not to be confused with the device's screen width or other widths.

Comment: Hi Jaime. Thanks. Given that it is in relation to the Card face, the question I have then is the space between the Card Face with and the full width of the device screen itself. Based on our testing, there seems to be padding between that, and we'd like to know what that space is. @Jaime Lopez Jr.

Comment: That isn't specified because it can vary quite a bit. For example, experiment with adjusting the width of your browser window when logged into Banno Online. Notice that the width of plugins will change based on the responsive layout. Plugin content should be responsive to adapt to varying widths per https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/.