# Why does application give unsupported width error, and ask to rotate device?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

'unsupported width' error that states the minimum supported widgth is 320 pixels, please rotate your device to see the full page. Currently there was a minimum height set in banno, but not any width set.
This support 320 min width, which they will do in the current banno integration. They have a border. So even if the screen is 320 pixels wide it is effectively adding 32 pixels of border to make all the 288 pixels in width.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're talking about the behavior in [Banno plugin framework sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73027836/banno-plugin-framework-sizing) (specifically, the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fx4X.png), then that behavior is within the plugin's content *itself* and isn't due to Banno.

The "Unsupported Width" behavior will have to be changed by the plugin's author. As noted in [Banno plugin framework sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73027836/banno-plugin-framework-sizing#comment129009460_73029349), the plugin's content must be responsive to adapt to varying widths per https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/.